# How to change an attribute in a subnode in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to change the attribute value (in this case "51") of the "NextMemberId" in an xml file that looks like this:

```
<File>
  <MemberList>
    <NextMemberId Value="51" />
    <Member Id="1" ..... />
    <Member Id="2" ..... />
  </MemberList>
</File>
```

The following code works, but I would like to know if it can be done in a more direct way without having to run a foreach loop:

```
var memberId = 1;

var memberlist = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MemberList");

foreach (XmlNode node in memberlist.ChildNodes)
{
  var nodeElement = node as XmlElement;
  if (nodeElement != null && nodeElement.Name == "NextMemberId")
  {
    nodeElement.SetAttribute("Value", memberId.ToString());
  }
}
```

Thanks for any inspiration!

Comment: Are you able to move to LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) instead of XmlDocument? It will make it much simpler...

Comment: Don't actualle know - I'm working with embedded solutions in VS2008?

Comment: It would help to put that in the question, along with what framework you're targeting. When you're working with a platform that's nearly a decade old, if you don't specify that in the question you may well get answers that are perfectly valid for everyone else, but don't help you.

Answer (score 2):

The correct path to get `NextMemberId` from `File` according to your sample XML would be :

```
var nodeElement = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MemberList/NextMemberId");
nodeElement.SetAttribute("Value", memberId.ToString());
```

If there are multiple `NextMemberId` in your actual XML, and you need to filter by `Value` attribute, then you can add an XPath predicate similar to what the other answer suggested :

```
var nodeElement = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MemberList/NextMemberId[@Value=51");
```

Notice that you can choose to *keep or leave* single-quotes around `51` depending on whether you want compare the `Value` as *a string or a number*, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can select single node with specified attribute like this:

```
var nextMemberIdNode = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("NextMemberId[@Value='51']")
```